# Magento 1.9 Get table of products for pending orders

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get a list of products from only pending orders!
i have this is code but works only for register customers i need to show product for all orders  even for guests and multi store.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
//Get All Users/Customers
$users = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($users as $user){
$customer_id = $user['entity_id'];

//Get the  all orders by customer id
$order_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id)
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending')))
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc'); 

    foreach($order_collection as $orders) {
        echo $increment_id = $orders['increment_id']."</br>";
        $order_id = $orders['entity_id'];

        //Get all items for the order id
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

        $items = $order->getAllItems();

        foreach($items as $i) {

              echo $i->getName()."</br>";
        }

        echo  "</br>";
    } 

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code. Guest customers don't have an ID. So it's better to remove customer condition.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
//Get All Users/Customers
//$users = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

//foreach ($users as $user){
//$customer_id = $user['entity_id'];

//Get the  all orders by customer id
$order_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    //->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id)
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending')))
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc'); 

    foreach($order_collection as $orders) {
        echo $increment_id = $orders['increment_id']."</br>";
        $order_id = $orders['entity_id'];

        //Get all items for the order id
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

        $items = $order->getAllItems();

        foreach($items as $i) {

              echo $i->getName()."</br>";
        }

        echo  "</br>";
    } 

//}
?>
```

Comment: Hello the code is working tank you

Comment: i need to add custom attribute to table

Comment: Please post another question for it. and close this one

Answer (score 0):

i need to add custom attribute text value to table how do i get the value ?

```
    <?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

//Get All Users/Customers
  //  $users = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
 //     ->addAttributeToSelect('*');



//Get the  all orders by customer id
$order_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
   // ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id)
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending')))
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc'); 
echo '<table><tr><th>Comanda</th><th>Produs</th><th>qty</th><th>SKU</th></tr>';
    foreach($order_collection as $orders) {
       // echo $increment_id = $orders['increment_id']."</br>";
        $order_id = $orders['entity_id'];

        //Get all items for the order id
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

        $items = $order->getAllItems();


        foreach($items as $i) {

              echo '<tr>
              <td>'.$orders['increment_id'].'</td>
              <td>'.$i->getName().'</td>
              <td>'.$i->getQtyOrdered().'</td>
              <td>'.$i->getSku().'</td>
              <td>'.$i->getCod().'</td><tr>';
        } 
        } 
        echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```